# Using Zookeeper with Solr but only have 2 servers

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I am new to Solr and am experimenting with SolrCloud - and it seems that ZooKeeper is the best way to manage high availability.

However, in our production environment we only have two servers (active-active) and I am concerned that Zookeeper is not ideal on two servers because if either of them goes down the whole ensemble stops working. The workaround so far is to run two ZKs on server1 and one ZK on  server2, so that at least if server2 goes down we still have quorum (but if server1 goes down, game over).

What is the best practice / recommended solution for Solr in this scenario? Can it automatically replicate/fail over with SolrCloud between 2 servers without using zookeeper? Or is there some way to use Zookeeper (or another tool?) so that it is robust over 2 servers? Or do I have to go back to using the legacy-mode replication?

Thanks!

Comment: very relevant issue..we are facing with same problem..Matt how did you resolve this finally?

Comment: I'm afraid there was no "correct" solution in the end - we ran 2 ZKs on one server and 1 on the other...

Comment: Hi Matt, i am facing the same exact issue now, did you find a better solution? If not, did running 2 zK 1 server + 1 zK 1 server as an ensemble, run smoothly? Thanks in advance for sharing.

Comment: @jumping_monkey yeah it ran fine in terms of performance - but "if" the server with the 2 zookeepers crashes, you lose the whole cluster, so it's something to be aware of

Comment: Hi @Matt, thanks for getting back. I guess the value add of this configuration( i.e 3 instances of zk on 2 servers, v/s 1 instance of zk on 1 server) is that if 1 server crashes, the zk configs would still be available on the other running server, and can be used to bring up the "crashed" server? I am just thinking out loud, which option is "better". Your thoughts please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are going to need more than 2 servers. A production Zookeeper ensemble needs at least 3 instances and should always be an odd number:

> Three ZooKeeper servers is the minimum recommended size for an
>   ensemble, and we also recommend that they run on separate machines.
>
> For reliable ZooKeeper service, you should deploy ZooKeeper in a
>   cluster known as an ensemble. As long as a majority of the ensemble
>   are up, the service will be available. Because Zookeeper requires a
>   majority, it is best to use an odd number of machines. For example,
>   with four machines ZooKeeper can only handle the failure of a single
>   machine; if two machines fail, the remaining two machines do not
>   constitute a majority. However, with five machines ZooKeeper can
>   handle the failure of two machines.

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html

Running 2 instances on 1 server doesn't really cut it, as losing that server will kill the cluster. Solr Cloud requires Zookeeper - you can't get around it.

> **Setting Up an External ZooKeeper Ensemble**
>
> Although Solr comes bundled with Apache ZooKeeper, you should consider
>   yourself discouraged from using this internal ZooKeeper in production,
>   because shutting down a redundant Solr instance will also shut down
>   its ZooKeeper server, which might not be quite so redundant. Because a
>   ZooKeeper ensemble must have a quorum of more than half its servers
>   running at any given time, this can be a problem.
>
> The solution to this problem is to set up an external ZooKeeper
>   ensemble.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble

Generally speaking trying to run truly distributed, large scale processing with less than 3 servers is a bad idea - Zookeeper is not unique in it's requirement for at least 3 servers to support reliable operation if a server fails. Generally you need a quorum of surviving servers (N/2+1) to function, so you need to start with at least 3.

Comment: In this case, we want to deploy a solution to a client who can only provide us with two servers (we told them three, they just don't have a third one). Is there absolutely no better way? Otherwise I will have to use the legacy master/slave replication and if master fails, manually re-point the dns to slave. Will be a real shame if we can't leverage SolrCloud.

Comment: You can deploy zookeeper with 1 or 2 servers, but if you lose one be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks John. In your experience, if you only had two servers, how would you set it up?

Comment: If I had only 2 servers and I needed to setup a production Solr Cloud environment I would go with 3 ZK processes, 2 running on 1 server. That way if you have a software issue and a ZK process failed (as opposed to a hardware failure) you would still have a quorum. And if the server with only 1 ZK process failed I'd still have a quorum and half of the Solr Cloud cluster to recover from. But I would be unhappy about it.

Comment: @JohnPetrone In Production environment, should Solr be setup on every server possible including the one having Zookeeper? 
Lets say i have 5 servers, should i run Zookeeper on 3 and Solr on 2? Or 
Zooper on 3 and Solr on 5?

Comment: @user3815757 that's well outside the scope of this question - I'd ask a new question

Comment: @JohnPetrone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274433/solr-and-zookeeper-configuration Done.