# Solr Cloud - what is the recommended number of zookeepers per solr instances?

Tags: solr

As i understand it is recommended to have an odd number of zookeepers as explained here [Using Zookeeper with Solr but only have 2 servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694296/using-zookeeper-with-solr-but-only-have-2-servers).

I wanted to know what the recommended number of zookeepers is for a certain numbers of solr instances.

Let's say i want to know for x solr instances how many zookeeper instances do i need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general - 5 is usually a good number if you have a fair amount of servers. More servers means less write performance, but slightly better read performance. Five is good because it allows you to remove a server for upgrading while still having a healthy cluster.

From the [Zookeeper FAQ #7](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/FAQ#A7):

> 7. How do I size a ZooKeeper ensemble (cluster)?
>
> In general when determining the number of ZooKeeper serving nodes to
>   deploy (the size of an ensemble) you need to think in terms of
>   reliability, and not performance.
>
> Reliability:
>
> A single ZooKeeper server (standalone) is essentially a coordinator
>   with no reliability (a single serving node failure brings down the ZK
>   service).
>
> A 3 server ensemble (you need to jump to 3 and not 2 because ZK works
>   based on simple majority voting) allows for a single server to fail
>   and the service will still be available.
>
> So if you want reliability go with at least 3. We *typically recommend
>   having 5 servers in "online" production serving environments*. This
>   allows you to take 1 server out of service (say planned maintenance)
>   and still be able to sustain an unexpected outage of one of the
>   remaining servers w/o interruption of the service.
>
> Performance:
>
> Write performance actually *decreases* as you add ZK servers, while
>   [read performance increases modestly](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperOver.html#Performance).
>
> See this page for a survey Patrick Hunt (http://twitter.com/phunt) did
>   looking at operational latency with both standalone server and an
>   ensemble of size 3. You'll notice that a single core machine running a
>   standalone ZK ensemble (1 server) is still able to process 15k
>   requests per second. This is orders of magnitude greater than what
>   most applications require (if they are using ZooKeeper correctly - ie
>   as a coordination service, and not as a replacement for a database,
>   filestore, cache, etc...)

i.e. the size of your cluster isn't really the limiting factor, but more important is how many queries you'll have against Zookeeper in total (and not queries in Solr). You probably won't have any issues until you're entering a very specialized domain in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Equation : `2n+1`

where n is max number of node failure to handle. say u want to keep zookeeper cluster service up and running if upto 2 zookeeper nodes goes down. you should consider(2*2+1)=5 zookeeper instances in a cluster(ZooKeeper ensemble).