# ZooKeeper 2 Server ensemble

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to run a zookeeper ensemble with 2 machines? I understand there are other posts about a 2 server ensemble. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694296/using-zookeeper-with-solr-but-only-have-2-servers) sounds a lot (more like exactly) like the issue I am having and there it states that there is no solution. However there is a page on Apache's website for zookeeper that explains a [dynamically changing zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/zookeeperReconfig.html#ch_reconfig_upgrade) ensemble which allows for it to change from standalone single server to multiple servers. I want to have fault prevention on just 2 machines that are connected to zk ensemble.

Is there still no way to run a zookeeper ensemble with 2 machines?

Comment: It's recommended to have an odd number of Zookeepers. While 2/3 will function if one goes down, achieving quorum for leader election requires a 'tie breaking" machine

Comment: You could run a zk with only 2 nodes in 2 different machines. But the cluster would fail to work if at least one node crash since zk requires the majority nodes alive (2 / 2 + 1 = 2)